# Replace exact insensitive match of a string of interest while ignoring other strings having part of it

Tags: python, regex, string, replace, string-substitution

I am having difficulties replacing exact insensitive match of a string without affecting bigger strings having part of the string of interest.

What I mean is: if I have a string "INFO", I want to replace it with "INFORMATION" and if for instance I find a string "INFOR" I do not want to do anything because it is not exact match of "INFO".

I did this in python:

```
string = re.compile(re.escape("info"), re.IGNORECASE)
string = string.sub("information", "This might be related to info disclosure. Because Infor disclosure....")
print(string)
```

I am getting as output:

> This might be related to information disclosure. Because informationr
>   disclosure....

which is not what I want because **infor** is being replaced by information**r**

Any way to solve this?

Comment: You can add spaces around the match, or you can match against `info([^r])` and then just replace with information + matched group

Comment: works with spaces as you suggested, but then one cannot rely on it. Let's say I have "info." with full stop and not spaces and I still want "info." to be "information." ....

Comment: Use word boundary as: `string = re.compile(r'\binfo\b', re.IGNORECASE)`

Comment: @anubhava, thanks that works. If you add as answer I accept it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions will solve your problem.
you can use re library and you should just put space before and after "info":

```
import re
string = re.compile(re.escape(" info "), re.IGNORECASE)
string = string.sub(" information ", "This might be related to iNfo disclosure. Because Infor disclosure....")
print(string)
```

Comment: This solution would fail when info has no space... for instance ".info." or "bla_bla\info" or "info." 
@anubhava commented on the post to add word boundary in the re.compile, that solves the problem for all cases.